# SSRS/BIDS 2008 Unable to load the credentials. Type is not in the serialization whitelist

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, bids

I am unable to run a report from bids when connecting to ANY (local, and remote) server. The local report runner comes up with the following error:

An error occured during local report processing.
Unable to load the credentials.
Type 'Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Project.Credentials' in assembly 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.Designer, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91 is not in the serialization whitelist.

Some things to note:

- This happens on a remote server as well as my local server
- This happens when using a SQL Server user/pass as well as my windows credentials
- I definitely have authorization to the machines in question
- This used to work just fine on my machine, but I can't point to a change that caused the error
- Other developers are still able to develop and run reports as normal

My environment:

- Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit
- BIDS 2008
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise and Developer (remote, local)

Does anybody have any ideas as to the cause of this, or hints to help me troubleshoot?

Comment: Is this a specific project that you are experiencing this, or does the issue span multiple BIDS projects? Have you tried repairing your installation via the SQL Server Installation Center (Maintenance > Repair)?

Comment: Can u show the error of capture image ? . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Testing SSRS using BIDS/Visual Studio has many bugs, secret caches and is kinda meaningless anyway (assuming your end users dont use BIDS). I usually deploy everything to an SSRS server and run all tests there.

It's also much more convenient - you can leave multiple browser windows open and just click the Report Viewer Toolbar's Refresh button after you deploy report changes.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this exact issue. It impacted all BIDS projects in my case. So I made some tests in different machines and this issue seems to happen only in some environments (i.e., it din't happen in a machine with windows 7 32bit).

In windows 10 (64 bit) I had this issue, but here changing the credentials in the datasource of the BIDS projects to "Use Windows Authentication" seems to work fine (as long as the logged user has the required permissions in the datasource of course).